# What happens when the same observable is measured twice in a row?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, observables

I have the understanding that the outcome of measuring the same observable twice in a row on the same state is getting the square of the eigenvalue if and only if the state is an eigenstate of the observable. Is it true?

Otherwise $\langle O \rangle \psi_n = n \psi_n$ would not hold, right?

Comment: True. The onservable should have an eigenvalue.

Comment: You do not get the square, but the same eigenvalue.

Comment: If you get a different value in the second measurement, you weren't paying attention to the experimental setup and something else happened between measurements, or your measurement tool is broken.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the Stern-Gerlach experiment. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Gerlach_experiment  That page has a simple diagram showing the outcome of spin measurements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have the understanding that the outcome of measuring the same
>   observable twice in a row on the same state is getting the square of
>   the eigenvalue

If you measure the observable $O$ and get a value $o_1$, then you immediately measure $O$ again, you'll get the value $o_1$ and *not* $o^2_1$.  This is because the first measurement leaves the system in the state $|o_1\rangle$.

Note:  *measurement of an observable $O$ is not equivalent to acting on the state with $O$*

This is most easily seen by acting on a superposition of eigenstates of $O$

$$O(c_1|o_1\rangle + c_2|o_2\rangle) = c_1o_1|o_1\rangle + c_2o_2|o_2\rangle$$

which is not an eigenstate of $O$.  But, according to the measurement postulate, immediately after measuring $O$, the state will be an eigenstate of $O$.

Comment: What do you mean by 'acting on the state with O'?

Comment: @JD_PM, 'acting on the state with O' means the *operator* $O$ takes as input the state vector and produces as output another state vector, e.g., $|\psi_b\rangle = O|\psi_a\rangle$